# No me reconoce los componentes de mi item.xml para llenar el recyclerView con la clase de ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

estoy tratando de llenar un recyclerView con datos que provienen de Firebase RealtimeDatabase. Mi problema es que al momento de asignarle al holderView.itemView a cada una de las variables de la clase que contiene los aributos de la base de datos, el itemView (que proviene del ViewHolder), no me reconoce los elementos de la interfaz de item_actividades.xml

```
    package com.example.turistiandoapp.ui.actividades

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.turistiandoapp.Publicaciones
import com.example.turistiandoapp.R
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

class ActividadesDisponibles : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var mRecyclerView : RecyclerView
    lateinit var database : DatabaseReference


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividades_disponibles)

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Actividades")
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvActividades)
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(this))

        logRecyclerView()
    }
    private fun logRecyclerView () {

        var firebaseRecyclerAdapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Publicaciones, ActividadesViewHolder>(
            Publicaciones::class.java,
            R.layout.item_actividades,
            ActividadesViewHolder::class.java,
            database
        ){
            override fun populateViewHolder(viewHolder: ActividadesViewHolder, model: Publicaciones, position: Int) {
                **viewHolder.itemView.tViewNombreActividad.**setText(model.nomActividad)
                Picasso.with(this@ActividadesDisponibles).load(model.imagen).into(**viewHolder.itemView.imageVActividad**)
            }
        }
        mRecyclerView.adapter = firebaseRecyclerAdapter
    }

    class ActividadesViewHolder(val itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    }
}
```

Lo que tiene asteriscos o que esta en negrilla, es la partes donde le asigno al elemento de la vista cada uno de los atributos de la base de datos(solo tengo atributos)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageVActividad"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tViewNombreActividad"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nombre_actividad"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_bold"
            android:textSize="25dp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tViewPublicadoPor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/actividad_por"
                android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_bold"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tViewNombrePublicador"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/publicardor"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_bold"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tViewDescripActividad"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:text="@string/descrip_actividad"
            android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_bold"
            android:textSize="19dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Este es mi layout con cada uno de los elementos que se deben mostrar al momento de llenar el recyclerView

No se si me falta algo para que me reconozca los elementos de mi item_actividades.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven aquí no me reconoce ningún elemento de la vista :(

¿Debo importar algo a la clase de ActividadesDisponibles.class para que me reconcoza los elementos de la vista de item_actividades?

Answer (score 0):

Para poder acceder a `itemView` tienes que guardarlo como atributo de la clase al instanciarla. Esto es, crea un atributo en la clase que se llame itemView, dándole el valor del que entra como parámetro a la clase.

`var ìtemView : View = itemView`

Otra manera de hacerlo es obtener cada una de las vistas en el ViewHolder, como por ejemplo:

`var imageVActividad : ImageView = itemView.imageVActividad`

Y así con todos los elementos de tu layout. De esta manera podrás acceder a ellos directamente con `viewHolder.imageVActividad`.